# Ruby 3.2.3 shows large increase in Heroku Free Memory Slots Metric

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, metrics

**Previous Ruby Version ‘3.1.4’**
[image: Ruby free memory slots]

**Updated Ruby Version ‘3.2.3’**
[image: Ruby free memory slots]

After Upgrading Ruby to 3.2.3, it is showing a larger variation in the Heroku Free Memory Slots Metric. There is no change in the memory usage though, we tried upgrading memory to 2GB. Still, there is no change in the Free Memory Slots Metric.

We are not able to figure out what is causing this change in the Free Memory Slots Metric. Did anyone face a similar issue before?